# Is 'netlogon' user needed?

Tags: users

I have a user called `netlogon`, which must have been automatically created by some application or by... someone(?). Is it necessary or can I just delete it?

Comment: Do you really have a netlogon user ('grep netlogon /etc/passwd'), or is it that there is a directory under home, /home/netlogon?

Comment: Actually, grep netlogon /etc/passwd shows nothing at all. So does it mean there's no user with this name (I'll get ashamed because of the nobbishness of my question, then)?.... But then.... what is that folder for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a directory created to store Samba "netlogon" scripts, when Samba has been configured "domain logons." It's safe to leave there or delete if you do not use it. No shame! We're in a constant learning process, no?

Comment: ...yes we are :o